# how to solve InvalidValueError: at index 0: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to make a poly line in google maps,
but I'm retreiving the data first in my db.
and then to my php file and to my script file.
the following is how i generate my json data in my DBPHPfile.. sorry if its a bit messy

```
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $cleaned = clean($row['longlat']);
    $count =true;
    $temp = 0;
    $temp2 = 0;

    for($x = 0; $x <= strlen($cleaned)-1; $x++){
      if($cleaned[$x] == ' '){
        $temp2 = $x - $temp;
        if($count == true){
          array_push($long, remove_spaces(substr($cleaned, $temp, $temp2)));
          $count = false;
        }
        else{
          $count = true;
          array_push($lat, remove_spaces(substr($cleaned, $temp, $temp2)));
        }
        $temp = $x;

      }
    }
    $temp2 = strlen($cleaned) - $temp;
    array_push($lat, substr($cleaned, $temp, $temp2+1));
  }


  $finalroutes = array();

  // finalizing my routes

  for($x = 0; $x<sizeof($long);$x++){
    $long[$x]=remove_spaces($long[$x]);
    settype($long[$x], "float");
    $lat[$x]=remove_spaces($lat[$x]);
    settype($lat[$x], "float");
    array_push($finalroutes, "{lat: $lat[$x], lng: $long[$x]}");
  }
   echo json_encode($finalroutes);
```

then my script is this

```
$(function(){
      $('#go').click(function(){
        var longtemp = $('#long').val();
        var lattemp = $('#lat').val();

        $.ajax({
          url:"dbphp.php",
          method:"POST",
          data:{longtemp:longtemp, lattemp:lattemp},
          success:function(data){
              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 18, center: {lat: 8.264670, lng: 124.263394}, mapTypeId: 'terrain'});
              flightPlanCoordinates = JSON.parse(data); //from here
              // var newflights=[];
              // for(var i = 0; i <flightPlanCoordinates.type.length();i++)
              //   newflights[i]=flightPlanCoordinates[i];
              console.log(data);


              flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
              });//to here
              flightPath.setMap(map);
          }
        })
      })
    })
```

i marked where the problem is so you can find it easily.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON. Can you share the code that generate the json?

Comment: what is `array();` ?

Comment: ive added the part where in what i do with my data..
and sorry if its soo messy. the data that im passing is the $finalroutes

Comment: @epascarello im not sure sir what your question implies

Comment: you've put a string in each element of the array ... `array_push($finalroutes, "{lat: $lat[$x], lng: $long[$x]}");` ... so, that's your issue - put an object (or whatever PHP calls it) in there instead

Comment: @JaromandaX im a bit confused sir..
so what data type should i pass? a single string containing all the supposed elements of the array?

Comment: answer below is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
array_push($finalroutes, "{lat: $lat[$x], lng: $long[$x]}");
```

With

```
$finalroutes[] = ["lat" => $lat[$x], "lng" => $long[$x]];
```

This way you will have the correct array, that later you be encoded as json in `echo json_encode($finalroutes);`